# Erro edmx Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

Senhores, não consigo atualizar uma tablela no sistema, o qual, faço manutenções devido a seguinte mensagem :
The model was generated with warnings or errors.
Please see the Error List for more details. These issues must be fixed before running your application.

Ja tentei deletar a tablela e inserir no edmx, porém, não consegui ter sucesso ! Alguém pode me ajudar com isso.

Comment: Tenho um projeto em produção que sempre da erro no edmx se eu tento atualiza-lo. O que eu faço é remover tudo e inseri-lo novamente.

Comment: não tem mais detalhes sobre o que está acontecendo?

Comment: Olá - Marcos Junior, infelismente não. Quando vou atualizar seja pelo "Update model from Database" ou apagando o objeto e adcionando novamente não funciona (Ele mostra a mensagem de erro em questão), para mapear foi necessário inserir manualmente no edmx abrindo com o  editor Xml (Escrevendo dentro do código xml) e depois criando o campo no diagrama (botão direito sobre a tabela add new scalar property), só dessa forma consegui atualizar.